# .NET 7 API project can't find images

Tags: asp.net-web-api, razorengine

I began with a standard .NET 7 Web API project that runs fine. I ran into a situation where I need to return a one-off view and I didn't want to create another project to serve views so I added a normal controller to the project with a method to return said view. The view gets returned as expected but none of the resource links work, including images.

So this html:

```
<a href="index.html" class="logo">
    <img src="images/popupshop.svg" alt="">
</a>
```

returns this view:

[image: boken image link]

This is how I have added the image to the product:

[image: visual studio project]

Not sure what else I'm missing?

Comment: try to change src to `src="~/images/popupshop.svg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

to the Program.cs allowed the paths to work